# no wireless connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a new partition and even though I can connect wired, wireless connection is not working.

I works perfectly on Xubuntu 14.04 on another partition, but on the new installation of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 I can see my connection but when I add the password nothing happens.

[Network diagnostics output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16030392/)

Comment: The wireless network adapter driver seems fine and detects many wireless networks but it isn't associated to any. What's the exact issue here? What happens when you try to connect to a known-to-work wireless network?

Comment: I can see the connections, and when I write the password of my home network nothing happens, not even an intent of connecting, nothing.  That is the exact issue.

Comment: This is important information related to the issue; please clarify that in your question! Can you please try to connect, then [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and include the output in your question? It should now include some info on the network association process.

Comment: should I do it connected to the wired connection? or I should disconnect Internet an try offline?

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the difference with the previos output then? I already did that. (thanks)

Comment: As I said, the diagnostics should now include some info on the network association process in the last section. If you tried to join a wireless network recently before running the diagnostics, then there would be no point in doing it again, though. I don't see any hints to an attempted network association though. Compare with this from my machine: https://paste.ubuntu.com/16040754/